# Array Discontinuities

Tags: c, arrays

So I'm trying to create the general form of a matrix that when 2N=6 looks like (6x6)

```
1 0 0 -1/1!    0    0  
0 1 0 -1/1! -1/1!   0  
0 0 1 -1/2! -1/1! -1/1!  
0 0 0 -1/3! -1/2! -1/1!  
0 0 0 -1/4! -1/3! -1/2!  
0 0 0 -1/5! -1/4! -1/3!
```

That is to say a N=3 gives a 6x6 matrix with the
identity in the TL quadrant
null in BL quadrant
and -1/ factorials from 0 to N-1 in the columns, shifting down by one.

I'm trying to do this as generally as possible. So far I have:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main()
    {
     int A, B, C, R, M;
     int i, j, N;
     double n,r,c,rf,x;

     N=3;
     n=N;
     M=(N+N-1);

     double a[(2*N)][(2*N)];

     for(A=0; A<N; A++)
     {a[A][A]=1.0;
     }

    for(C=N; C<=M;C++)
      {
      for(R=(C-N);R<=(M);R++)
        {
        r=R-(C-N);
        rf=1;
        for(x=1; x<=r; x++)
            {
                   rf=rf*x;
            }
                a[R][C]=((-1)/rf);
        }
      }





    for (i = 0; i < 2*N; i++)
      {
        for (j = 0; j < 2*N; j++)
        {
          printf(" %f ", a[i][j]);
          if (j % 3 == 2) printf("  ");
        }
        printf("\n");

      }

       /*
      for(i=0;i<=M;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<=M;j++)
      {
      printf("[%d][%d] = %f \n", i, j,a[i][j]);
      }
    }
    */
    return 0;
    }
```

I've included (but commented out) an individual element print out. This works for N=3 but when trying in increase the value of N I encounter some really odd results and cannot figure out why, can anyone help? (e.g N=4, a[2][0] goes to a enormous number) there's no "debugging error" in that it compiles and runs. Don't mean to ask people to debug but wondering if there's a general property of arrays that I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: What odd results do you encounter? Have you tried to use a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: *there's no "debugging error" in that it compiles and runs* -- I don't think you understand the meaning of the word "debugging".

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your array to have all zeros to start with:

```
double a[(2*N)][(2*N)] = {0.0};
```

Otherwise the elements that you never write a value to have indeterminate values.